# Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning to all! I am trying to post some content automatically with a GET request with Google Sheets and I can't, as that error keeps appearing.

With an URL like the following one "https://script.google.com/macros/s/(ID script)/exec?p1=5&p3=see", I would like to populate some fields on the sheet.

Following my code, the data should appear in this format in the sheet:

B3: see

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I am using:

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("(ID)");

  sheet.getRange("A"+e.parameter.p1).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
  sheet.getRange("B"+e.parameter.p1).setValue(e.parameter.p3);
  sheet.getRange("C"+e.parameter.p1).setValue(e.parameter.p4);
      }
```

Comment: If you include p2 and p4 it works just fine. Otherwise it still works but but you get undefined in the other two columns

Comment: @Cooper you were right! Thank you very much! I haven't slept too much, it was a very stupid mistake haha. Btw, one question: my code will only work on the main sheet of the spreadshet. Do you know what can I do to make it work in another sheet of the same spreadshet? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try this: `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("(ID)").getSheetByName(sheetname);`